# MySQL: Loading local data is disabled

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java program, one of the tasks of which was to upload data from a plain text file into a table of a MySQL 5.7 database.This has worked without problems so far. I recently moved the database to MySQL 8.0 and recompiled the Java program, with the mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar library. After that, however, I received the following error message when uploading:

Loading local data is disabled: this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

After reading a little about the problem, I found that two things need to be specified in my.ini to eliminate the error. I put these in. (secure-file-priv was already in)

```
[client]
local_infile = 1

[mysqld]
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"
local_infile = 1
```

Then, after restarting the mysql service, unfortunately the situation did not change.
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
local_infile = ON

Maybe something should be done differently in the Java program?
It currently looks like this:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/testdb?user=root&password=pwd123");
stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.executeUpdate("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads
/something.csv' INTO TABLE data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '' (field1,field2,field3,field4)");
```

When compiling Java, the environment was JavaSE-1.8 (jdk1.8.0_281).
However, the error still exists. In which direction do you think I should continue my research?

Comment: Well, you seem to be curiously mixing a MySql 'import' with a Java programmatic approach. Since your mix seems to be contain more of the former and that's not working out for you, why don't you go for a pure programmatic approach? How many rows in the file, out of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing often stems from MySQL Connector/J having the `allowLoadLocalInfile` property turned off by default. This is a security measure in the connector to prevent potentially malicious files from being loaded from the client to the server.

To resolve this, you can change the way you establish the connection by enabling the allowLoadLocalInfile property:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/testdb?user=root&password=pwd123&allowLoadLocalInfile=true");
```